# How can I install uwsgi on yocto without pip and doesn't have it's own recipe?

Tags: yocto, uwsgi, yocto-recipe

I need to install uwsgi and I am creating using yocto. However, there is no recipe for this and I also cannot find install procedure without using pip. Is there some ways or examples to follow?

I'm currently using:
BB_VERSION 1.32.0
BUILD_SYS  x86_64-linux
DISTRO poky
DISTRO_VERSION 2.2
python 2.7.12
flask 0.11.1

I'm expecting build a webpage utilizing nginx, flask, and uwsgi.
Currently I'm using react framework and nginx and it all shows up correctly, except uwsgi I have no idea how to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download it manually as said in the documentation: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html